# How can I align the vertical arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I am trying to make the following diagram compact and aligned for aesthetic reasons.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={shift left}]
        &\mathcal{F} U_i \arrow[rr,shift right=.25ex, "\mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j\subset U_i)"]&& \mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j)\\
        \mathcal{F} U \arrow[ur,shift right=.25ex] \arrow[dr,shift right=.25ex]\arrow[r, shift right=.25ex, dashrightarrow, "e"] &\displaystyle\prod_i\mathcal{F} U_i \arrow[rr,shift left=.125ex,"p"] \arrow[u] 
        \arrow[rr,shift right=.675ex,swap,"q"]\arrow[d] &&\displaystyle\prod_{i,j} \mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j) \arrow[d]\arrow[u]\\
        &\mathcal{F} U_j \arrow[rr,shift right=.25ex, "\mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j\subset U_j)"]&& \mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j)
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the vertical arrows are not aligned. Would it be possible to align them? Also I would like the reduce the verticle length of the diagram and make it a bit compact, how can I do this?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @hpekristiansen
Sorry for the issue. I have edited my question

Comment: Spelling tip: vertical.

Comment: I have added another answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did not understand all the different shifting of arrows, so I removed it and made `row sep` smaller:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=0.4cm]
&\mathcal{F} U_i \arrow[rr, "\mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j\subset U_i)"]&& \mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j)\\
\mathcal{F} U \arrow[ur] \arrow[dr]\arrow[r, dashrightarrow, "e"] &\displaystyle\prod_i\mathcal{F} U_i \arrow[rr,"p"] \arrow[u] 
\arrow[rr,shift right=.675ex,swap,"q"]\arrow[d] &&\displaystyle\prod_{i,j} \mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j) \arrow[d]\arrow[u]\\
&\mathcal{F} U_j \arrow[rr, "\mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j\subset U_j)"]&& \mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j)
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: Cumulative diagram with formulas]

Comment: Probably better is to use one of the standard sizes: `row sep=small`

Comment: Also there is a special option: `cramped` specifically to make everything more compact.

Comment: How do I use the ```cramped``` option?

Comment: e.g. `\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=small, cramped]`

Answer (score 2):

Following the guide http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/images/4/41/Xyguide.pdf of `xy` package it is possible to realize the same pictures and the same tips with this package like `tikz-cd`. Obviously it's a very particular package and sometimes it's also difficult to understand especially for me that I don't get along very well with English.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=2pc@C=4pc{
 & \mathcal{F} U_i  \ar[r]^{\mkern-30mu\mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j\subset U_i)}& \mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j)\\
\mathcal{F}U\ar[ru] \ar[dr] \ar@{-->}[r]^e & \displaystyle\prod_i\mathcal{F} U_i \ar[u]\ar[d] \ar@<-.5ex>[r]_{q}
\ar@<.5ex>[r]^{p} &\ar[d]\ar[u] \displaystyle\prod_i\mathcal{F} U_i \\
 & \mathcal{F} U_j \ar[r]^{\mkern-30mu\mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j\subset U_j)}& \mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j)
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @Boltzee You can see that the tips are the same but they are a more lenghts instead of tikz-cd.

Comment: they look almost the same except for the length of the arrows, I personally find the tikz one simpler

Comment: @Boltzee Surely :-) I have add this example only for comparison. For my opinion the lenght of the arrows is better instead of tikz-cd.